# bootstrap dropdown odd ipad behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, events, ipad

On a site I am working on we have a bootstrap dropdown which has top level menu items which are <a> tags with the href attribute set.

Bootstraps documentation does say your not supposed to do this.

On most devices clicking/touching this top level link causes it to follow the link effectively making the dropdown useless.

However for some reason it behaves differently on Ipad

On Ipad if a top level link has a dropdown touching it opens the drop down and does not follow the link. If the top level link does not have a dropdown or its dropdown is already open then touching it follows the link.

I cannot figure out why.

While debugging it with safari dev tools no events fired when the top level menu items were touched at times when it did not trigger it to follow the href link but the dropdown menu did open.
Touching the top level menu links at times when it did trigger it to follow the href triggered click and mouse down events.

This happens on both Safari and Chrome in Ipads

Can anyone explain what is causing Ipads to behave this way?

Answer (score 0):

Seems IOS handles *:hover* differently from other devices

[humanwhocodes.com on iOS :hover problem](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/)